# The user study methods for mobile and web application testing

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, mobile-web, usability-study, testing

A mobile version of the website facilitates ubiquitous access to the service, but it seems to me that there are some differences in user needs between the mobile and desktop versions. I conclude the following points:

1. obviously screen size
2. interaction and input types(i.e. touch vs click)
3. Environment and location (mobility of the user)
4. how the users read and the context of the use
5. portable and interruptible

Having this said, I want to know do we have to do a different user testing on the different groups? What are the differences and user programs? In my own POV, I think it should be better if we have the same group of users for testing. And all I can think off is having an interview (focus group/1-to-1), eye tracker, and questionnaire. However, even I can list so many differences between mobile and desktop. I don't have any idea how the testing method will be different. Welcome all discussion cuz this bothers me a long time ago since I start my project. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Christie, it sounds like you might be looking for a place to start. Have you done any research on how your mobile users' needs differ from your desktop users? Or are you potentially looking to start there?

Comment: @lzquierdo I have done some secondary research on that. My problem is I am not sure what test should I do to distinguish the differences between the two groups so I have no idea to start off

Comment: @CodingKingggg something that I think would help is to find any stats or analytics that you have on the types of tasks and screens viewed and whether these are done on desktop or mobile devices. This will give you a good starting point for how to differentiate between the user groups, as well as work out what is in common. Chances are that it might turn up something significant, or maybe not depending on what your application actually does.